# what is the order to be evaluated in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I tried two type of joining condition in `Redshift` first I tried `where` after `join on` and second,I tried `and` after `join on`.I assumed that `where` is executed after `join` so that in this case it must be scaned so much rows.

```
explain
select
    *
from
    table1 t
    left join table2 t2 on t.key = t2.key
where
    t.snapshot_day = to_date('2021-12-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

```
XN Hash Right Join DS_DIST_INNER  (cost=43055.58..114637511640937.91 rows=2906695 width=3169)
  Inner Dist Key: t.key
  Hash Cond: ((&quot;outer&quot;.asin)::text = (&quot;inner&quot;.asin)::text)
  -&gt;  XN Seq Scan on table2 t2  (cost=0.00..39874539.52 rows=3987453952 width=3038)
  -&gt;  XN Hash  (cost=35879.65..35879.65 rows=2870373 width=131)
        -&gt;  XN Seq Scan on table1 t (cost=0.00..35879.65 rows=2870373 width=131)
              Filter: (snapshot_day = '2021-12-18 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
```

on the other hands, as follows,`and` is conditioned before `join` so that I assumed it is less rows to be scaned in `join`. but it returned too much rows and consume huge cost as follows greater than `where` clause

```
explain
select
    *
from
    table1 t
    left join table2 t2 on t.key= t2.key
and
    t.snapshot_day = to_date('2021-12-18', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

```
XN Hash Right Join DS_DIST_INNER  (cost=40860915.20..380935317239623.75 rows=3268873216 width=3169)
  Inner Dist Key: t.key
  Hash Cond: ((&quot;outer&quot;.key)::text = (&quot;inner&quot;.key)::text)
  Join Filter: (&quot;inner&quot;.snapshot_day = '2021-12-18 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
  -&gt;  XN Seq Scan on  table2 t2  (cost=0.00..39874539.52 rows=3987453952 width=3038)
  -&gt;  XN Hash  (cost=32688732.16..32688732.16 rows=3268873216 width=131)
        -&gt;  XN Seq Scan on table1 t  (cost=0.00..32688732.16 rows=3268873216 width=131)
```

What is the difference between them ? where do I misunderstand in this case ?
If someone has opinion or materials please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are several things happening here (in my original answer I missed that you were doing an outer join, so this is a complete rewrite).

1. `WHERE` happens before `JOIN` (ie, real-world databases don't use relational algebra)

   A join merges two result-sets on common column(s). The query optimizer will attempt to reduce the size of those result-sets by applying any predicates from the `WHERE` clause that are independent of the join.
2. Conditions in the `JOIN` clause control how the two result-sets are merged, nothing else.

   This is a semantic difference between your two queries: when you specify the predicate on `t.snapshot_day` in the `WHERE` clause, it limits the rows selected from `t`. When you specify it in the `JOIN` clause, it controls whether a row from `t2` matches a row in `t`, *not* which rows are selected from `t` or which rows are returned from the join.
3. You're doing an outer join.

   In an inner join, rows between the two result-sets are joined if and only if all conditions in the `JOIN` clause are matched, and only those rows are returned. In practice, this *will* limit the result set to only those rows in `t` that fulfill the predicate.

   An outer join, however, selects *all* rows from the outer result-set (in this case, all rows from `t`), and includes values from the inner result-set iff all join conditions are true. So you'll only include data from `t2` where the key matches *and* the predicate applies. *For all other rows in `t` you'll get nulls.*
4. That `DS_DIST_INNER` may be a problem

   Not related to the join semantics, but for large queries in Redshift it's very expensive to redistribute rows. To avoid this, you should explicitly distribute all tables on the column that's used most frequently in a join (or used with the joins that involve the largest number of rows).

   If you don't pick an explicit distribution key, then Redshift will allocate rows to nodes on a round-robin basis, and your query performance will suffer (because every join will require some amount of redistribution).